# Setting value of RadioButtonFor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, radiobuttonfor

I just saw an implementation of `RadioButtonFor` with `true` or`false` as 2nd parameter, but how do I set the checked value using JavaScript?

I already have an existing code that sets the checked value of a radiobutton via Id in `JavaScript` and only using `@Html.RadioButton` in View. But what I want now is to use `RadioButtonFor`. How do I do this? My active and inactive has the same Id, both rbtn only differs in value.

PS: Not working code is at the bottom part of the JavaScript

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public string userStatus { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.userStatus)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.userStatus, "Active")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.userStatus, true)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.userStatus, "Inactive")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.userStatus, false)
```

part of Javascript:

```
//columnData - represents the column index in my table
//fieldId - id of the fields (e.g. text = userDesc, radio = userStatus)

for (i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {
    //Evaluates what type an input is
    var elmntType = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).getAttribute("type");

    if (elmntType == "text") {

        document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[i].innerHTML.trim();

    } else if (elmntType == "radio") {

        var status = rowSelected.cells[i].innerHTML.trim();

        //I just invented this but it's not working
        if (status == "Active") {
            document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).checked = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).checked = false;
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: You can always give your radio buttons an specific `id` (and you should be doing that of removing the `id` anyway) - `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.userStatus, true, new { id = "userstatus-true" }`) (ditto for `new { id = "userstatus-true" }`) and then `$('#userstatus-true').prop('checked', true);` or you can refer to then using `$(input[type="radio"]).first();` (or `.last()`). But you code suggests a table, meaning you have multiple rows, meaning your generating invalid html.

Comment: I used to do that too, my only concern with `new { id = "myId" }` is that it looses it's value when I'm passing it to a controller using `AJAX`, it took me a lot of time to debug why I'm passing a null value only to know that it doesn't work with `new { id = "myId" }`. I suspect that's because of the `new`.

Comment: And also I want it to be dynamic to other radiobuttons too. So specifying a specific id will defeat that purpose. Unless I specify all other radiobuttons to have an id of `rActive` and `rInactive`

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop to create multiple rows of an object - in which case you doing it wrong anyway. Its a bit unclear what you trying to do. What is your ajax and what method are you trying to post to?

Comment: If you are using inline javascript you can get generated id by using `@Html.IdFor(m=>m.userStatus)`

Comment: @Stephen I think I'm not creating multiple rows of an objects. By dynamic, what I mean is that I can use my javascript on another `Views`. The ajax and method is another matter. What I just noticed is when I use the `new` keyword on `input` in `View`, its `document.getElementById` `getAttribute` method in JS will only return `null` values.

Comment: `new` has nothing to do with it. It unclear what you trying it do here - why would you want to **set** the value? If you wanting to get the value, then its `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right! When I changed my radiobutton t's not being passed to my javascript because I'm not changing the parameter when I call the script -_- Thanks for the tip! I'll check again you're first code. I apologize for the inconvenience